# Case of Ruby performing better than Java

Tags: java, ruby, performance, benchmarking

I am doing a presentation about the Ruby ecosystem targeted at a Java crowd.

Even though I will make the points about time gain from productivity and that *slower* can still be *fast enough*, it will be nice if I can come up with a benchmark that shows Ruby outperform Java in some sort of number crunching, once the question comes up, for pun's sake.

---

Unfortunately, after hours of searching and experimentation, I still got nothing.

Could anyone come up with a benchmark that shows things are not completely black and white?

Ideally, it should compare latest versions of **java 1.6**/**1.8** against latest version of **cruby**. Any examples involving **rubinius**/**jruby** are also appreciated.

Comment: If you've been trying to do experiments yourself and can't come up with benchmarks that support your hypothesis, that might well indicate your hypothesis is false.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, that is probable, but I am still open to the possibility that there might be some obscure corner case. There is no harm in asking.

Comment: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=yarv&lang2=java might indicate places where Ruby is at least in shouting distance of Java and places where Ruby isn't.

Comment: java did spend thousands of man-years on performance improvement:)

Comment: I don't think "java" spent any time. Open-source developers and corporations did though.

Comment: Show them line counts of similar projects written in each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll end up using a simple regex example - `/(foo|bar)*/`, trying to match `'foobar' * n`:

---

```
puts 'Done matching' if ('foobar' * 666).match(/(foo|bar)*/)
```

---

#### VS

---

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class SimpleRegexTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String repeatedFooBar = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(666, "foobar"));
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(foo|bar)*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(repeatedFooBar);

        if (m.matches())
            System.out.println("Done matching");
    }
}
```

---

It's not technically faster, the **java** version doesn't even work (throws a `StackOverflowError`). This IMHO is far superior case against the notion that **java** is better optimized for every possible scenario out there.

It also gives me a nice transition to talk about code terseness, especially after I show the pre-**java8** version.

Answer (score 15):

I don't think you are going to find something. When it comes to optimization, Ruby and Java are actually pretty similar, the main pain point for both are boxed objects and dynamic method dispatch, which they both inherited from Smalltalk (Ruby directly, Java via its [main inspiration Objective-C](http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/java-objc.html)). And the Java VMs are quite simply the most advanced production execution environments for dynamically-dispatched OO languages there are. There may be some research stuff for Scheme, for example, that is even faster, but when it comes to production-ready industrial-strength implementations, [Azul Zing](http://azulsystems.com/products/zing/), [Oracle HotSpot](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/), [Oracle JRockit](http://oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/), [IBM J9](http://ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/) and friends win hands down.

So, unless the [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) guys have invented something that the Smalltalk/Java community have overlooked, you'll pretty much end up with same performance at best.

Your best bet is *not* numerical processing but text processing. That's something where Ruby's Perl heritage shines. Most Java implementations' regex engines aren't very performant (although they are getting better), whereas [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo) is actually quite good (not as good as Perl's, though). Plus, Ruby's character-encoding independent strings allow you to eliminate re-encoding your string, whereas Java's strings will always have to be encoded to and from UTF-16, unless the input and output encodings are UTF-16, which is highly unlikely. In Ruby, you need to transcode at most once, even if your input and output encoding are different, you can set the internal encoding to be the same as either the input or the output encoding, and thus you only have to transcode during either input or output, but not both.

There *are* examples, though, of Ruby competing with C, and since "everybody knows"™ that C is faster than Java, this surely must mean that Ruby is faster than Java, right? **Right?**

[Actually, finding examples where Ruby outperforms C is probably easier, since dynamic optimizations like speculative inlining, polymorphic inline caching, adaptive optimization, as well as "unsafe" optimizations enabled by dynamic de-optimization don't exist in typical C implementations.]

In particular, Rubinius's [`Hash` class](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/hash.rb) which is written in Ruby is not significantly slower than [YARV's `Hash`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c) class which is written in C.

And a really exciting example is that [JRuby+Truffle+Graal+TruffleC](http://chrisseaton.com/rubytruffle/) can run YARV C extensions *in a C interpreter on top of the JVM*(!!!) faster than YARV can run C extensions natively:

- [*Very High Performance C Extensions For JRuby+Truffle* by Matthias Grimmer and Chris Seaton](http://chrisseaton.com/rubytruffle/cext/)
- [*Dynamically Composing Languages in a Modular Way: Supporting C Extensions for Dynamic Languages* by Matthias Grimmer, Chris Seaton, Thomas Wuerthinger, Hanspeter Mössenböck, in Proceedings of the 14th International Conference on Modularity, 2015.](http://chrisseaton.com/rubytruffle/modularity15/rubyextensions.pdf)
- [*High-Performance Cross-Language Interoperability in a Multi-Language Runtime* by Matthias Grimmer, Chris Seaton, Roland Schatz, Thomas Wuerthinger, Hanspeter Mössenböck, in Proceedings of 11th Dynamic Languages Symposium (DLS)](http://2015.splashcon.org/event/dls2015-high-performance-cross-language-interoperability-in-a-multi-language-runtime)

[Of course, this latter example is actually an example of the power of [Truffle](http://ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Projects/JVM/Truffle.html) and [Graal](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/graal/), i.e. two Java technologies, more than it is an example of the power of Ruby.]

Comment: This is actually very informative. I even have a vague memory of a regex which was throwing `StackOverflowError` in java, but was passing in ruby. Nice materials, overview and directions. I will investigate it further.

Answer (score 0):

I once attended a talk by a JRuby developer who pointed out that they were getting better benchmarks from JRuby than from native Ruby, and that this was because Sun/Oracle had spent vast amounts of money on making Hotspot incredibly good at JIT optimisation.

I suspect you might be able to find some benchmarks in which JRuby is as fast as plain Java, once JIT has had a chance to do its magic.

So try a server application, maybe a web app, start it up and exercise the code at least once before beginning to measure performance. This should mean that JIT has happened, and you may find that performance is equivalent to plain Java.

Even so, a tractor isn't a race car. One is good at winning races, the other is good at pulling ploughs. Likewise, there are reasons why more than one language exists.